# Is looking at the correlation table between predictors an insufficient test for multicollinearity?

Tags: multiple-regression, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor

In some of these data science analyses that I've seen posted on the web, e.g., https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-regression-on-boston-housing-dataset-f409b7e4a155, they "test" for multicollinearity by looking at the correlation table between regressors, so if you see a pair of regressors with a large (in magnitude) correlation coefficient, you drop one of them because it'd otherwise introduce multicollinearity.

But this doesn't seem sufficient. This only allows you to see whether a regressor is (or approximately) a linear combination of *one* other variable, but this doesn't show whether a regressor is linear combination of 2 or more variables.

I think a better approach is VIF, but I rarely ever see this in these analyses, so I'm wondering if I'm misunderstanding something here, or most analyses don't require that level of detail?

My second question is, say you find a pair of predictors, by looking at the correlation matrix, that have high correlation (e.g.,  > 0.95). I think it's a sound approach to simply drop one of them, but does it matter which one you drop? I would think it doesn't since you can just write one as a linear combination of the other, and it therefore doesn't matter which one you keep or drop.

Comment: As far as your Q2 is concerned if they are measuring the same thing in slightly different ways why not put their average in instead of either?

Comment: @mdewey Is the correlation is so high that they're pretty much a linear combination of each other, what would putting in average accomplish that keeping one of the two variables wouldn't? It seems like ultimately, it'd give the same info?

Comment: If the errors of measurement are independent then the average will be more stable than either of its components. Of course if the errors are highly correlated that does not help. You can consider using the sum and difference of two predictors as a poor-person's version of PCA.